# Powershell Write-Progress and Adding Timer

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a PowerShell script for Microsoft Teams that looks at a list of Users in a .csv file and returns a few properties of the user, then exports it to another .csv with the results. This works fine except the progress bar is stuck displaying the last entry until I hit enter. How do you make the last entry disappear and only show "Done Executing Script" and return to C:>

[image]

Im trying to add the time at the end of the line when each of the lines from the CSV is executed, Please help me with that. Example below:

```
Processing User Number: 1 [Currently Processing: User1@abc.com] - Policies applied in "5s"
Processing User Number: 2 [Currently Processing: User2@abc.com] - Policies applied in "2s"
Processing User Number: 3 [Currently Processing: User3@abc.com] - Policies applied in "10s"
Processing User Number: 4 [Currently Processing: User4@abc.com] - Policies applied in "8s"
Processing User Number: 5 [Currently Processing: User5@abc.com] - Policies applied in "25s"
```

CODE FOR POWERSHELL SCRIPT:

```
Write-host "Connecting to Microsoft Teams....." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
Write-host "Successfully connected to Microsoft Teams" -ForegroundColor Green

$CsvFilePath = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\\Desktop\MicrosoftTeams\precheckbatch2.csv" 
$Count=0

$results = foreach ($UPN in $CsvFilePath) {   
$user = $UPN.UserPrincipalName 
Get-CsOnlineUser $user | Select-Object Displ*, UserPri*, IsSipEnabled, TeamsUpgradeE*, 
Enterprise*, @{l="FeatureTypes";e={$_.FeatureTypes -join "; "}}, @{l="AssignedPlan";e= 
{$_.AssignedPlan -join "; "}}

Write-Progress -Activity "Processing User: $Count" "Currently Processing: $user"
$Count++
}

$results | Export-Csv C:\Users\\Desktop\MicrosoftTeams\precheckdataresults1.csv
Write-host "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue of VSCode only. When I run this simplified script in the console, the progress bar disappears automatically, when the script ends. When I run it from VSCode, the progress bar stays visible, reproducing the issue.

```
foreach( $count in 1..3 ) {
    $user = "User$count"
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing User: $Count" "Currently Processing: $user"
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

To fix the problem for VSCode, add a `Write-Progress -Completed` line, to explicitly remove the progress bar:

```
foreach( $count in 1..3 ) {
    $user = "User$count"
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing User: $Count" "Currently Processing: $user"
    Start-Sleep 1
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Processing User: $Count" -Completed
```

Comment: Hi @Zett42, Thanks! I added write-progress with complete and it worked. 

I still dont know how to add a timer for each line in the CSV file. I want to achieve something like this. Please help.

Im trying to add the time at the end of the line as to how long the script took to apply certain policies for each User in the CSV, Please help me with that. Example below:

Processing User : 1 [Current Processing: User1@abc.com] - Policies applied in "5s"
Processing User : 2 [Current Processing: User2@abc.com] - Policies applied in "2s"
Processing User : 3 [Current]- Policies applied in "10s"

Comment: @Dillon I'm not sure if I understand correctly. You want output of `Write-Progress` to show in a new line for each user, so that when the script ends, the times for all users can be seen?

Comment: Hi @Zett42, Something like that but not only when the script ends but for each line that is been executed from the CSV. Busy doing a bulk migration in Teams using a script and applying multiple policies. Currently, the script runs but no progress per line of the imported CSV so u sit staring at the screen until it's done.

Processing User 1:  Policies applied in "15s" 
Processing User 2:  Policies applied in "25s" 
Processing User 3:  Policies applied in "10s"
Total Time to Process User is 50s